# Request is None in Non-orm Tastypie Resource flow

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I have the below code that seems to work fine except for having the `request` and `kwargs` as empty in `get_object_list`

```
class Target(object):

    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        self.id = 1 #Since tastypie needs an id
        self.x = x
        self.y = y



class TargetResource(Resource):
    x = fields.IntegerField(attribute='x')
    y = fields.IntegerField(attribute='y')

    def get_object_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
        targets = []
        print 'Got Request %s kwargs %s' %(request, kwargs) 
        target = self.obj_get(request, **kwargs)
        targets.append(target)

        return targets

    def obj_get(self, request=None, **kwargs):
       #Do something that requires the request and kwargs
       #Return an instance of Target


    def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
        kwargs = {}

        if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
            kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.obj.id
        else:
            kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.id

        return kwargs

    def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Filtering disabled for brevity...
        return self.get_object_list(request)


    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'target'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        object_class = Target
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(BasicAuthentication(), SessionAuthentication())
```

Answer (score 3):

`obj_get_list` is called by `get_list` ([tastypie/resources.py](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1287))

If you look at the `get_list` code:

```
def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        base_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)
        objects = self.obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle, *self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
        ...
```

You can see that that the request is passed in a bundle to `obj_get_list`.

So you should implement the following `obj_get_list` to get the request:

```
def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    return self.get_object_list(kwargs['bundle'].request)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `**kwargs` aren't populated because the normal `get_object_list()` doesn't take them.  From [tastypie/resources.py](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1047): `def get_object_list(self, request):`
As for `request`, something like:

```
def get_object_list(self, request):
    if request is None:
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
    # the rest of your get_object_list() code
```

should drop you into the debugger and let you figure out what code isn't passing the request in.